# New build won't boot

Tags: hardware-failure, computer-building

GA-970A-DS3 Gigabyte Motherboard AMP3+ socket FX4100 processor. This is a new build and won't boot. 550w PSU. CPU fan starts but shuts down immediately. All the pins seem to be fine and it is plugged into the Motherboard correctly. The Gigabyte support page says that the processor is supported.

Any Idea why it is failing to boot. Would bad Memory Sticks cause this? The memory is DDR3 dual channel 1333. How would I test the memory?

Comment: I had this - the 3 things to test are: RAM, PSU, Motherboard (my guess is it's faulty) or CPU (less likely although it just happened to me). Take it into a computer shop and ask them to test it all.

Answer (score 1):

If you pull the RAM out and power on the PC, the motherboard should beep an error code to you. From your post though it sounds like your computer isn't even posting, which is making me lean towards either power supply or motherboard dead.

Since this is a new build just swap your old power supply in and test that the motherboard will post, if you have the same result it sounds like your motherboard is DOA.